# Keep track of all files saved in a certain folder

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I would like to know if there is any solution to the following problem:
every day I create a folder (in my Linux system) whose name is parametrised by the current date. I then run a bunch of different scripts that save files in this folder. Some of the output files get overwritten more times by different scripts, and this is typically what I want to happen. A few times, though, I would like to "go back in time" to see how a certain file has been changing during the various steps.

Note that the files are always overwritten (typically by a python script) and never opened, edited and saved back with the same name.

Is there any way to do this? The only thing I could think of is some ad hoc configuration of subversion, git or other source code management systems. I could create a repo for the individual date (folder), but I would like it to keep track of all changes automatically, without updating the repo manually each time.

Any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a `backups` folder and within that folder are date folders `2016-02-21`, `2016-02-22`, etc.

Go into the `backups` folder and run `git init`.  This will initialize your git repo.  Add a Readme file, then you can `git add Readme` followed by a `git commit -m 'Initial commit'`.

Now your `backups` folder is kept track of via git.  You could change your scripts so that at the end of the script, it changes into the `backups` folder, does a `git add .` and then `git commit -m 'End of script XYZ'`.

Then anytime you want to see how `backups/2016-02-23/filename.txt` changed throughout the day, you can run `git log -p backups/2016-02-23/filename.txt`.